# what-is-the-sql-used-to-get transaction response time percentile from Loadrunner .mdb file

Tags: sql, load, loadrunner

I am working on a project where we are directly hitting the Loadrunner transactions .mdb file to extract the raw data.

> mdb is microsoft access database and stores information in various tables. Can any one please help me , which table to refer to get the response time related information? one table , which I picked was "BasicTransactionPercentile" , however this table seems to be very inconsistent , in one .mdb file it is there and in other its not.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

All of the tables and relationships in the mdb file are documented in the [Metadata] table, including primary and foreign keys.   For transactional information you will want to concern yourself with the raw data contained in the [event meter] table and its relationships.   You will need to pull the relations that you need from the [Metadata] table for event names of type transaction as well as a status of passed.

Unlike some other database engines, such as SQL Server and ORACLE, Access does not have a built in percentile function that you can leverage, which means you will need to write your own from base statistical functions.    Have you considered using SQL Server, even the express edition, as your analysis data store?

Comment: Thanks James, I am using MySQL to insert .mdb raw data-> My SQL using scripting language like Python. I refereed Meta data table and found one parameter Field Name as as "resp Time" however going to referred  table, doesnt give me info of response time data. Can you please help , where to look for?

Comment: I gathered info of pass/fail/run and stop status from table like "event meter and event_map, however , getting response time data is proving to be tough.

Comment: The Event meter contains all of the timing record data.  It should be ovious and straightforward for which field contains the response time.     Please include your query here to help us understand your challenge.

If you wish to import data then take advantage of the ability of the Analysis program to import datapoint data.

Comment: SELECT Event_map.[Event Name], Count(*) AS Samples, Min(Event_meter.Value) AS Minimum, Avg(Event_meter.Value) AS Average, Max(Event_meter.Value) AS Maximum, StDev(Event_meter.Value) AS [Standard Deviation], Sum(Event_meter.Value) AS TotalTime
FROM TransactionEndStatus INNER JOIN (Event_map INNER JOIN Event_meter ON Event_map.[Event ID] = Event_meter.[Event ID]) ON TransactionEndStatus.Status1 = Event_meter.Status1 
WHERE (((TransactionEndStatus.[Transaction End Status])="Pass")) 
GROUP BY Event_map.[Event Name] 
ORDER BY Sum(Event_meter.Value) DESC;

Comment: James, appreciate your help and Thank you for your query , I am getting Minm,Average, Maximum data points for transaction response time, however as we mostly deal with 90 percentile data (for response time) , can it be ex tractable? I Know if we query Event map and Event meter table , we would get all data points for each txns , but I am facing challenge on how to extract 90 percent out of it, If you can help , it would be very helpful to me , again Thanks for your time .

Comment: there is no percentile function in Microsoft Access.  You will need to construct your own from the statistical definition for percentile.  Or, if you use SQL Server as your data store then you can use built in functions in TSQL on SQL Serer for generating a percentile value

Comment: yup , this is what I feared for , however I have seen a table called "BasicTrasactionPercentile", which actually stores txns names and their percentile value" . However, the challenge is this table at times present in .mdb and most of the time it is not. I am wondering if this depand on the way we save .lrr to .lra to get transactions .mdb file from Load runner? if this mystery is solved , my or rather majority of ours issue will go . If you can share some experience of yours on this.

Comment: I don't know how much more clear I can state this.  Microsoft Access has no built in functions for percentile.  Go to your college statistics text and pull the definition of percentile from that text.  Use that definition to construct your own query to generate the percentile that you want.   From a vendor perspective you are way outside a limitation of support once you start running queries directly against the data.  From a peer support once you ask for the query to be constructed then you are in the realm of consulting.

Answer (score 0):

Using the jackcess API, here is the guts of how you extract transactional stuff from the mdb file via Java.

You can get the list of 'transaction' event ids from the Event_map

```
Table table = db.getTable("Event_map");
```

You can then go thru the 'Event_meter' table and pick the transaction events you want, Here is the outline for transaction execute and elapsed times

```
Table table = db.getTable("Event_meter");
for (Row row : table) { .....
    //  The txn recored time "End Time" is the relative end time in seconds to 3 decimals of the txn.  Storing as epoch time in msecs  
    Double txnSecsFromStart =  (Double)row.get("End Time"); 
    Long txnEpochTimeMsecs = new Double( runStartTimeEpochMsecs + txnSecsFromStart * 1000 ).longValue();
    lrEventMeterBean.setEndTime(txnEpochTimeMsecs.toString()); 

    BigDecimal rawValue  = new BigDecimal((Double)row.get("Value"     )).setScale(6, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal thinkTime = new BigDecimal((Double)row.get("Think Time")).setScale(6, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);                 
    lrEventMeterBean.setValue( rawValue.subtract(thinkTime));
```

.... //so on for the other fields

Note: "runStartTimeEpochMsecs" is obtained from the 'result' table

As data manipulation is pretty limited in Access, we load the extracted data into a mySql db. Then getting values like the 90th percentile, that match to the Analysis report is possible (took a bit of work!).

PS:  And remember the mdb file I am talking about here has the data for the entire test, filtered data is handled differently. IMO filtered data is too complex to worry about (the magic and complexity of the Analysis Report is what you are paying for after all ...).   Again, we use our mySql db for basic filtering.