# How to extract time specific data from different LoadRunner tables?

Tags: loadrunner

This questions is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505953/what-is-the-sql-used-to-get-transaction-response-time-percentile-from-loadrunner). I can get different metrics and transaction response time data based on the relations mentioned in Metadata table.

One thing I still have not been able to accomplish is that - how to extract time specific data from different LoadRunner tables? For example, I want to see how Login transaction performed between 9AM to 10AM of a 24 hour test. I can see that Event_meter has a column named [End Time], but I still unable to interpret that value to some clock time like 9AM.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time in the event meter table is an offset to the beginning of the test.  If you look in the result table you will find the [Start Time] and [Result End Time] of the test.   This is UNIX/Epoch time (seconds - 10 digit field).  You will also find an offset from your timezone.

The [End time] in the [... meter] tables is an offset from the [Start Time] of the test.   So, if your test started at 8am and the period you are interested in is +1 hour to +2 hours into the test, then you would look at the [End Time] range of 3600 to 7200 seconds.   The key here is in understanding the start time of your test, which can be viewed in human readable data format inside of the analysis report for execution time of the test.  Or, you can use any number of internet or publicly available functions to convert the [Start Time] in conjunction with the [Time Zone] field to find the start time and then calculate the offsets on the [End Time] for your Meter data.

Comment: This is awesome! Now I am able to get all the data that I need. Thanks a ton! :)